# Swapping to a new page

Tags: php, html, database, session

I just need some clarification.

I need to get my PHP page to move from one page to another once the 'submit' button is clicked. I presumed it was

```
$_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID'];
header("location:newpage.php");
}
```

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated to these newbie!!

Comment: It looks fine, what's the issue it is giving you? The closing bracket `}` might be causing an issue if you didn't open it properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move to other page after clicking the submit button. It will be better to add action tag to your form.
Example:

```
<form method="GET" action="newpage.php">
  <input type="submit" value="Send me to new page" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Zaynetro. How does it work with my submit form if its already in a form?   '<fieldset id="submit-form">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Record" />
          </fieldset>
        </form>'

Comment: where is your openning tag for 'form'?
<form action="newpage"><fieldset id="submit-form"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Record" /></fieldset></form>

Answer (score 0):

`header()` only works prior to any output.  You can't use it in an interactive way like this.  Try [zaynetro's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19639953/2057919) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could output an redirect from javascript once your php is done (assuming your form processor is on the same page with the html) . For example:

```
       $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID'];
        if($_SESSION['ID']){
       ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = 'newpage.php';
        </script>
        <?php } ?>
```